# How to read fetch wav file one by one in matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, wav

this is my Matlab code, I want to read .wav file from the same file or another file.

```
str=['1.wav';'2.wav';'3.wav';'4.wav';'5.wav';];
for i=1:5
    [y, fs]=wavread(str(i));
    a = miraudio(str(i));
    z = mirzerocross(a)
    close all
end
```

it gives me error like..
    Error using TRYFINAL (line 1)
    Error using vertcat
    Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Comment: Maybe write `str=['1.wav';'2.wav';'3.wav';'4.wav';'5.wav'];`? The semicolon is the vertical concatenation operator; no need to use it at the end.

Comment: Also, `str(i)` will give you a single char, not the full file name.  Put it in a cell array instead and use `str{i}`.

Comment: same error without ; at the end

Comment: str{i} is working thank you , but if i want to fetch .wav file directly from folder or any other .m file one by one or in for loop , how to do it??

Comment: I would recommend using the `.name` field of the items in the structure returned by [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) with [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) in your `wavread` call

Comment: can please give me example??

Answer (score 1):

Your OP is failing because of how MATLAB [character arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-character-arrays.html) are implemented (@patrik has a very good explanation in [this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29702515)). If you want to use a character array every row must be the same length, requiring you to pad the entries somehow which, while doable, isn't very efficient. The alternative is to use [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), as @nkjt suggested, which will work for the implementation outlined in your OP.

A more general approach, however, is to use the data structure returned by MATLAB's [`dir`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) command to identify all of the `*.wav` files in a directory and perform some operation on all of them.

```
pathname = 'C:\somewavfiles'; % Full path to a folder containing some wav files

wavfiles = dir(fullfile(pathname, '*.wav')); % Obtain a list of *.wav files

% Loop over all the files and perform some operations
for ii = 1:length(wavfiles)
    filepath = fullfile(pathname, wavfiles(ii).name); % Generate the full path to the file using the filename and the pathname specified earlier
    [y, fs] = wavread(filepath);
    a = miraudio(filepath);
    z = mirzerocross(a);
end
```

I have used [`fullfile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fullfile.html) in a few places rather than concatenating strings with a slash in order to avoid compatibility issues between operating systems. Some use `\` and others use `/`.

Also note that, as explained by the documentation, you can use wildcards (`*`) in `dir` calls to narrow down the list of files returned.